# How to automate the generation of a given String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to generate a String array that would contain time intervals:

```
[0]: "00:00-01:00", [1]: "01:00-02:00", ..., [23]: "23:00-00:00"
```

How can I automate the creation of such array?

This is what I've done so far, but it's not fully correct:

```
numHoursPerDay = 24;
int[] count = new int[numHoursPerDay];
String[] intervals = new String[numHoursPerDay];
for (int i=0; i<numHoursPerDay; i++)
{
    intervals[i] = "0"+i+":"+(i+1)+"0";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `String.format`:

```
for (int h = 0 ; h != 24 ; h++) {
    String intervalStr = String.format("%02d:00-%02d:00", h, ((h+1)%24));
    ...
}
```

`%02d` formats the number to two decimal places, optionally adding a leading zero.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/s6xnW4)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
intervals[i] =  String.format("%02",i) + ":00-" + String.format("%02",(i+1)%24) + ":00";
```

---